# Duplicate cells in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have read some explanations around here on why this tends to happen but I cannot figure out a fix for my case, which might be super easy.

I have a `UITableViewController` which has 2 sections and 20 rows in each section.

I want to add a `UISwitcher` in the second row so I've implemented the following:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as? SettingsCell else {
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
    switch indexPath.row {
    case 2: cell.addSwitcher()
    default: break
    }
    return cell
}
```

Everything works as expected until I scroll up and down, and then I'll have switchers in every row after a while.

Is there a way to release or perform a cleanup in the `dequeueReusableCell` or am I missing something here?

Here's my `addSwitcher()` function

```
public func addSwitcher() {
    accessoryView = switcher
    switcher.addTarget(self, action: #selector(switcherDidChange(switcher:)), for: .valueChanged)
    hasSwitcher = true
}
```

Comment: Probably a cleaner approach is to dequeue a different type of cell for the second row; a cell,that contains the switch.

Comment: @Paulw11 I have thought on that, but wanted to reduce code duplication and subclassing, so I added functions for those specific items to be added at specific indexes... but I might do it in the future to avoid these kinds of bugs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sure this is because of cell dequeing , that's when you set it for the that cell and scroll , other shown cells below it get that same cell from `dequeueReusableCell` , so you need to assign a nil to `accessoryView` to clear any previous view assigned to it

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! SettingsCell
cell.accessoryView = nil
```

you can also override `prepareForReuse`